# What to do with answers to low quality questions?

Tags: discussion, answers, down-votes, low-quality-posts

Would it be ethical (or acceptable) to dislike an answer to a low quality question for encouraging poor quality question, or would it be better to comment under the answer? What about flagging it for moderator intervention?

I am not sure if this question has been asked before, if it has been then feel free to point it out and flag this question for closure.

Regards.

Comment: If you aren't interested in the question then simply move on to one you find of interest. Others may find the question highly interesting and contribute answers that greatly enrich the site. Don't lose sight of the fact that the value of the site is in the *answers*, not the questions. The questions are merely sparks to motivate anwerers.

Comment: @BillDubuque No, don't get me wrong. I am not saying the question is uninteresting. I am saying the question is just lazy. That is, it is of the form: a car with velocity x travels y meter, what is the total time of travel. That is it, there is nothing more to it, Directly copied from a textbook without any work shown. This sort of question, if I recall, is against math SE policy, right?

Comment: Then it is likely an (abstract) duplicate so search for a good dupe target and help to organize the site. This is one of the best ways to handle FAQs and routine exercises that appear every year / term in minor variants ("eternal September").

Comment: @BillDubuque 'Don't lose sight of the fact that the value of the site is in the answers, not the questions.' I strongly disagree with you on this. Good questions are equally important. Even the 'Electorate' gold badge encourage us to vote more on questions

Comment: @YuiToCheng The value of the site lies almost entirely in the *answers*. The questions could be written by a bot. The answers cannot. Readers don't come here to learn how to write questions. They come here for *answers*. *Never*  lose sight of that.

Comment: @BillDubuque Please do not lose sight of the fact that it is your **personal opinion** that the value of the site lies "almost entirely" in the answers, not the questions.  Others strongly disagree, and are of the opinion that the value of the site lies in the *association* between good questions and answers.  Good answers are hard to find when they are attached to poor questions which are not easily searchable.

Comment: @XanderHenderson Spot on!

Comment: @YuiToCheng Spot on!

Comment: @BillDubuque By "good questions" I mean questions that are good in content, i.e. interesting and inspirational. You seem to refer to questions with context and mathjax formatting.

Comment: The question has certainly been discussed here before. See, e.g., https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16341/what-to-do-when-other-users-answer-low-quality-questions? and some of the questions linked there.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Perfect, thank you. Regards

Comment: @XanderHenderson And everything you wrote above is your personal opinion.  And this site is so large and diverse that it goes without saying that for most opinions there will be others who disagree. What's the point of stating the *obvious*?

Comment: How *ironic*. This question itself is "low quality" by the personal opinions of those who are (too-much) concerned with such inconsequential matters, e.g. no research effort (if the OP had searched they'd quickly learn that it has been discussed many times over the last decade), and undefined key terms ("low quality question", "dislike an answer") make it difficult to precisely comprehend and answer. Being a low quality FAQ - it was handled precisely as I proposed, viz. close it as a dupe.

Comment: @XanderHenderson In order to better understand your fuzzy claims I looked at the 4  latest questions that you answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3168656/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/763128/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3145781/242) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3143084/242). These don't support your claims. They appear to be what you call "PSQs" - which you normally close & delete in CRUDE. So I find your claims unfounded (and hypocritical).

Comment: @YuiToCheng What do you think "should be done" with the answers to the 4 "low quality" questions in the prior message?

Comment: @YuiToCheng And there appear to be more "PSQ"s than not in your answers, e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3093636), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3158412), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3108160), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3107286), [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3104948). Again, what do you think "should be done" with those answers to these "low quality" questions?

Comment: @BillDubuque Feel free to close them.

Comment: @BillDubuque [(1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3168656/242) The question cites a text (Enderton) and gives an example of their confusion (e.g how does one interpret $A = \{1,2,3\}$ as a set of sets).  A short question can still provide adequate context.

Comment: [(2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/763128/242) Even by today's standards, I don't think that this question is a PSQ.  That being said, it is quite old, and appears to be the target of many duplicate questions.  .  I had an alternative answer which I thought added to the already-present answers.  You will also note that I heavily caveated my answer, and explained *why* I was answering it by way of introduction to my answer.x

Comment: [(3)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3145781/242)  Context is given in the form of an actual definition, followed by a request for clarification vis-a-vis a specific example.  Moreover, it is not a PSQ in the sense that it isn't a something which is likely to be presented as an exercise in a textbook. It is also tagged [tag:terminology], which gives further context.  Finally, it is a common question (e.g. the mathematical definition of "increasing" might differ from the vernacular definition) and should probably have an answer on MSE...

Comment: ...As the question is reasonably well presented and I could not find a dupe target, I answered it.

Comment: (4) If you examine the [timeline](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3143084/timeline), you will note that I voted to close that question, and only answered after it cleared the review queue.  Moreover, I answered it in order to address what I saw as inadequacies in the other answer (i.e. applying the binomial theorem leaves out an important induction argument which could just as easily be applied directly).  I would be *happy* to see that question deleted, but if it is going to remain on the site, then it should, at least, have an answer which is more elementary.

Comment: @Xander Given that you and other CRUDE menber's have voted to close & delete thousands of very similar "low quality" questions, I find your backpedalling  attempts at justification to be quite amusing (and sad). If you don't apply the same standards to your own answers how do you expect those of opposing views to take you seriously?

Comment: *Sigh*  @BillDubuque Is it possible for you to comment without being so very condescending?  I am quite tired of your continued incivility.  I've explained *exactly* why I answered each of those questions.  I am attempting to engage with you in good faith.  In return, you offer insults, but no concrete arguments.  I'm done.  Good day.

Comment: @YuiToCheng But those are suppossd to closed (& deleted) according to *your* standards, not mine (as you argue above). So why are you advising *me* to close them. Post them in the CRUDE room if you wish to demonstrate that you apply the same standards to yourself as you do to others.

Comment: @BillDubuque It seems like you are taking this question to heart, no need to feel offended if people disagree with YOUR PERSONAL OPINION.  Opinions are just that-opinions. Please be courteous. Regardless, seems like you have quite a lot of time on your hands. Wouldn't it be better to utilize that time by doing something truly constructive... like answering low-quality which you OPINE are useful, for instance. Lol.

Comment: @BillDubuque "Illogical claim" and "false arguments," right... "illogical" according to who? "False argument," again, according to who?

Comment: @BillDubuque My standard is quite versatile... In particular, I never assert a question without context _must_ be bad. Also, I'm not your enemy. Sometimes, I'm in support of your suggestions. For example, you said downvotes on answers must be justified. I'm on board with you.